# Maintain same gaps between words in the html textarea using white spaces

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form with inputs, displays content into HTML textarea element with javascript.

I have used pad `secondWordInput.padEnd(50, ' ')` for input to maintain fix width to 50 characters.
But somehow textarea collapses spaces and works unexpectedly.

Currect implementation:
[image: current output]

Expected output:
[image: expected output]

The first input is fixed 5 characters, the second word in a line may vary the length I expected the third word in a row should be vertical aligned.

Note: When I `console.log` the above lines in a log they are maintaining 50 characters width correctly.
[image: console log]

Sample code

1. html template

```html
<textarea class="textarea" cols="30" rows="15" ng-model="$ctrl.vm.edl_file_content"></textarea>
```

2. angularjs

   seondInput = seondInput.padEnd(50, ' ');

   var event_data = "\n" + event + "  " + seondInput + "V   C       " + rest;

   ctrl.vm.edl_file_content += event_data;

Comment: You can use `console.table()`.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table

Comment: @ParthRaval thanks for the reply, I want to output into the HTML textarea element. in the console, it is working as expected.

Comment: Okay! can you please add your code snippet so, I can help you better.

Comment: @ParthRaval I have added sample code, its angularJS code. On submit event took input and added padEnd to the same and put the event into textarea. The main problem is that padEnd with character does add correct spacing and manage lenght for the event but in textarea it is not showing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the CSS font family.
I changed the font family of textarea element to monospace.

```
font-family: monospace;
```